# Valor NULL al pasar datos archivo json a php

Tags: json

Tengo un archivo json con este elemento:

```
{ 
    "id":"1",
    "nombre":"Luis",
    "Descripción":"Alumno"
}
```

El archivo php es así:

```
<?php 
$json = file_get_contents("json.json");

$data = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($data);
?>
```

Pues el `var_dump` me pone que es NULL. ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: A mi me funciona a la pefección tu código (array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["nombre"]=> string(4) "Luis" ["Descripción"]=> string(6) "Alumno" }). ¿Puede estar mal la ruta de acceso al archivo json.json?

Comment: la tengo en el mismo nivel de la carpeta

Comment: Haz un var_dump($json) después del file_get_contents para ver si el problema es traer el contenido o formatearlo después. Este es el resultado que sale (string(71) "{ "id":"1", "nombre":"Luis", "Descripción":"Alumno" }");

Comment: Si lees la página de [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) veras que este tipo de preguntas (¿Por que no funciona este código?) no son pertinentes. ¿Has debugado? ¿Has puedo alguna traza para saber si `$json` es un objeto válido? ¿porque no usas ningún control de errores?

Comment: @Carmen si que me lo coge pero luego decode no me lo hace bien

Comment: Vale, pues casi seguro que es un problema de codificación, necesitas que sea UTF-8, si no no va. Ahora te pongo un ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para montar el json los campos deben estar codificados en utf-8. Un ejemplo:

```
$result = array();
$result['id'] = (int)1;
$result['nombre'] = utf8_encode("Luis");
$result['descripcion'] = utf8_encode("Alumno"); //mejor no uses tildes en el nombre del campo

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
echo json_encode($result);
```

Y luego lo lees con tu archivo php. [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) requiere que la codificación sea utf-8.

```
$json = file_get_contents("json.php");
var_dump($json);

$data = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($data);
```

Ahora debería funcionar.

Comment: Pero el array ese lo tengo en el archivo json. Y aquí lo pones los valores en el PHP no?

Comment: Te he puesto un ejemplo creándolo con php por costumbre, yo me creo los json  con php porque me es más cómodo, y como he visto que estás creándolo me pareció más sencillo. Te corrijo la extensión del archivo que se me olvidó.

Comment: ya está solucionado muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro, no hay de que