# Por que me sale NULL al aplicar jsondecode en mi variable?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, jsonobject, jsonarray

Tengo el siguiente problema, obtengo esta data desde un jexcel y lo envio a un php

```
let data = spreadsheet.getData();
let data_import =  JSON.stringify({ data });
$('#data_import').val(data_import);
$("#action").val('import');
$('#form_import').submit();
```

Y lo obtengo en el php aqui:

```
$data_import = utf8_encode($post['data_import']);
$data_import_json = json_decode($data_import,true);
```

En el `$post['data_import']` llega la info bien y la muestro, pero al imprimir `$data_import_json` y me sale `NULL`, una posible solución?

Comment: puedes colocarl un ejemplo del contenido de `$post['data_import']` estoy casi seguro que el problema puede ser el contenido que manipulas...

Comment: tambien te recomiendo hacer el [tour] hay te regalan una medalla

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Valor NULL al pasar datos archivo json a php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/87447/valor-null-al-pasar-datos-archivo-json-a-php)

Comment: El contenido es el siguiente {"data":[["Alemania","Promigas","Guajira","Palomino","12312","123","13","123","123","123","321","312","31","312","312","312"]]}

Comment: Así logré resolver   $data_import = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $data_import); y luego si se aplicado el decode